# How to fix scroll lags in posts (only Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

When scrolling through an article on a site, when the cursor is on the table, the page starts to slow down when scrolling.

Most clearly to see in practice (in Google Chrome, Mozilla ok) https://outdoorsly.org/best-fish-finder-under-300/

It helps to disable Widgets in sidebar. But they are critically necessary.

How to win laggs without disabling the widgets in the sidebar

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  Only including a link to your website is not allowed on SO - see [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I can copy the source code of the plugin, what would be clearer?